# How can I lock contentOffset y position of a FlatList when new items are added

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatList with items in it. After I have scrolled down a bit, an item is added to the top. This causes the list to move down by one cell. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to scroll to the Y location (unanimated) when an item is added to the list

```
function itemAdded() {
    //...
    const listYOffset = this.state.listYOffset;
    const cellHeight = this.topmostItemHeight; 
    const newYOffset = listYOffset + cellHeight;
    this.listRef.scrollToOffset({ offset: newYOffset, animated: false });
    this.setState({ listYOffset: newYOffset });
}
```

Then in flatlist, set this `this.topmostItemHeight` to the height of the item added.

Note my code was used for adding one item at a time, but the fundamentals are the same

Comment: You should add more code example to improve this i.e. how does someone know the calculation for `this.topmostItemHeight` and `this.state.listYOffset`